# iphone UIWebView - Force show scrollbar always

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview

Is there a way to force the UIWebView to always show the scroll bar?

Comment: Don't you think user would find it distracting, and it occupies unnecessary screen space. Apple's way of animating the scroll bar into the screen when user starts to scroll is very nice. Why would you want to tamper with that? Why, o why?

Comment: Do you mean always allow scrolling (so it bounces), or show the scroll bars even when the user isn't touching the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fulfil your requirement, you must hard code in your code load any default page with some extra new line or blank spaces, which creates your page bigger than web view.